# ng test requires me to fix all linting before running any unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, tslint

The output of my `ng test` is as follows:

```
> ng test

24 12 2019 14:20:07.854:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
24 12 2019 14:20:07.860:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
24 12 2019 14:20:07.860:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
24 12 2019 14:20:07.865:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless

app/shared/forms/templates/templates.component.ts:11:1 - error TS6133: 'MatDialog' is declared but its value is never read.

11 import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
24 12 2019 14:20:11.633:INFO [HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Mac OS X 10.15.2)]: Connected on socket 9OfTSV7nahQakrDOAAAA with id 85821004
HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Mac OS X 10.15.2): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
HeadlessChrome 79.0.3945 (Mac OS X 10.15.2): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

The issue I am having is that if I have **any** linting errors in my src code, then unit tests will not run, which is extremely inconvenient when I just want to try things here and there for test-driven development. I would much rather just get the warnings for these linting errors and I can fix them all at once.

I am on Angular version, `"@angular/core": "8.1.2"` and Karma versions:

```
"karma": "4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
"karma-cli": "2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
"karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
"karma-verbose-reporter": "0.0.6",
```

On Angular 7 I did not have a problem with this, my unit tests would execute regardless of linting errors. I am not sure what has changed or which configuration I should be checking to stop this from occurring.

The end goal is for unit tests to be able to run regardless of any frequency of linting errors.

`angular.json` contains the configuration for tests:

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    ...etc...
```

**`karma.conf`**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-verbose-reporter')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'junit'] : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
    singleRun: false,
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: process.env.JUNIT_REPORT_PATH,
      outputFile: process.env.JUNIT_REPORT_NAME,
      useBrowserName: false
    },
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does it  behave the same if you run it with `karma start`?

Comment: I get `28 01 2020 08:56:56.615:ERROR [karma-server]: Server start failed on port 9876: Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.` when trying to run with `karma start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is TypeScript error, it means that `noUnusedLocals` is set to `true` in `tsconfig.spec.json`.

I think you can create inherited config i.e. `tsconfig.spec.dev.json` (use "extends": "./tsconfig.spec.json") and override `noUnusedLocals` value with `false`. Then you need to add `configurations` section:

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.dev.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
      }
    }
```

Now you can run dev as `ng test` or prod as `ng test --prod`.

Comment: Sorry, this is occurring on any linting errors. I want to ignore any linting errors and allow tests to still run but then still notify me of the linting errors. So effectively I would want `noUnusedLocals` to be set to something like `warn` rather than `false`. Setting to `false` would allow me to run tests but then I wouldn't see that error

Comment: It's compiler error and you will have to turn off all of them. Your IDE will most probably pick `tsconfig.json` for its language server so you will still see all errors in editor.